# Core Data - "days" and "tasks" (to-many-relation) - How to fetch all tasks of a day?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have the entities `Day` und `Task`. One day has many tasks and one task has many days.

I want to fetch all tasks of a certain day. I think you have to use predicates for that. I tried this:

```
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY days == %@", argumentArray: [Project.Days.current])
    fetchRequest.predicate = filterPredicate
```

But it's not working. Any ideas? I tried searching for this, but I just don't know what to search for, it's hard to describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test this at the moment but I think you would use 
`"%@ IN days"` as the predicate

Alternatively just fetch the day that you are interested in and use the array that contains the tasks

Comment: Thanks, not sure it's working, though. But maybe it's another problem. I'm taking a look into that, right now. Yeah, I thought about fetching the day, but I want to use it with an `NSFetchedResultsController` and I don't know if it works like this

Comment: Found the bug. I was using the cache that comes with `NSFetchedResultsController`. I removed it and now it works :). I think it would work in a real app. It probably only caused problems because I was messing up the code to test it.